# Vimeo Player is getting 404 error on Oembed Get call

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, vimeo, oembed

After uploading a video through the Vimeoo Tus upload approach, I redirect to a page to load a vimeo player object and attach it to a div. The player object gets a 404 from the Get request to retrieve the video information:

[image: chrome console error screenshot]

However if I enter the URL directly in the browser:

https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F522082785&id=522082785&width=960

it returns the json data for the video.

**My question is:**

1. How can I fix this?
2. If I can't fix it (due to vimeo's issues/processing,etc.), how do I handle it better and reload the player until the video shows up.

Additional info:

- the video is set to public and embed anywhere, it's not a privacy issue
- the videos do eventually load, after an unspecified time, so I suppose vimeo is processing them (although I can visit the video directly on vimeo)
- checking the transcode status on the completed upload before redirecting to the player page shows "complete"

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Same issue here. Even though `transcode` and `upload` are `complete` there is still an unspecified amount of time to wait until `oembed` stops throwing 404